# How to show sharing menus within activity?

Tags: android

I want to share a text using this:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

As you can see in the below picture, I know how to acheive a dialog which lets user picks his choice (My app). But recently I saw an app which is letting users pick their choice within its activity (Desired).
[image]

Any idea how to acheive desired one? Thank you all.

Comment: Use bottom sheet

Comment: As I said in comments of two answers, it's within the activity.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code, I've been using for sharing 'Referral Code' from within my app:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                .from(this) // getActivity() or activity field if within Fragment
                .setText("message") // This will be populated as user's message
                .setType("text/plain") // most general text sharing MIME type
                .setChooserTitle("Share code using:")
                .startChooser();
```

It opens up a view similar to your right image.

Comment: I implemented your code and the result is the same (like my app picture). The thing is that right image is not a BottomSheet, its within the activity like its a part of its layout.

Comment: @A.Badakhshan Then, I believe it is a custom view added at runtime to the current screen's layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the list of apps that are registered to handle the action and then display the result in the way that you like the most. When the user will choose something you can start the selected activity.

Comment: Yes I did that myself yesterday. :)

Answer (score -1):

Create Custom layout. (Right image)

Embed in `BottomSheetLayout`

Use `setState()` to show your "Share Screen"

`................................................`

or You can just do the same inside an AlertDialog. (Left Image)

Comment: It's not a bottom sheet. Its within the activity and its scrollable along anything else in activity.